# Bundle synchronization in B2C project

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am working on a B2C project.

We are using customized bundle implementation in our project.

However we were struggling with making bundle synchronization work.

With some effort, we managed to find the ImpEx to synchronize the Bundle:

```
 UPDATE CatalogVersionSyncJob;code[unique=true];roottypes(code)[mode=append];
;$syncJobCode;BundleTemplate,BundleTemplateStatus;
```

However, I am worried whether this will also synchronize the ChangeProductPriceBundleRule available out of the box.

Also how do I synchronize this from backoffice?Is running this cronjob from the Backoffice the only solution?How do Backoffice users see a Synchronize button?Is creating a separate node necessary?

Answer (score 0):

**How to synchronize from backoffice?**

1. Go to Backoffice
2. System -> Background Processes -> Jobs
3. Search for your sync job and use Sync button for panel

[image]

**Is running this cronjob from the Backoffice the only solution?**

You can schedule this job to run on specific interval (Cron Job)

**Is creating a separate node necessary?**

Not necessarily but you can customize if you want.

Hope it helps!